# Xamarin.iOS Could not find executable for C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Temp\mwk0whzy.yoa Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to run my Xamarin App for iOS on my own device with Visual Studio 2019 (Windows), but I keep getting this error:

Error Could not find executable for C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Local\Temp\mwk0whzy.yoa

Does somebody know the solution for this?

Comment: I recommend first getting it to work by building directly on your Mac, using VS Mac. If something isn't right, its easier to resolve it there. FIRST on Mac's iOS simulator, THEN on your own device, but still using VS Mac. THEN do "Pair to Mac" from VS on Windows, and try again from PC. (If you are trying to get this to work without a Mac - you won't get very far. Buy a Mac Mini.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thank you for your answer. I guess I have to buy a Mac then.

Comment: Having the same issue today in 2024 with .net MAUI. iPad local device was working fine just a couple of days ago, now it isn't.

Have tried rebooting, deleting obj/bin, clean/rebuild, haven't found a working solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today.

I resolved it by cleaning the project + deleting the `obj` folder manually.